# Limit of an definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Calculate
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n(ax^2+ax+1)}{e^x}.$$
>
> a) $0$
>
> b) $a$
>
> c) $2a+1$
>
> d) $\dfrac{2a+1}{e}$

I tried to note separated $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\cdot x^2}{e^x}$ with $I_{n+2}$ and to integrate it by parts until I have it in the function of $I_{n+1}$ and the Same $I_{n+1}$ in the function of $I_n$ but I got that the limit is $\dfrac{a+1}{e}$ and it is not there.

Comment: How large is the integrand in $[0,1]$, for increasing $n$ ?

Comment: Do you know the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: No. How is it?  It can be applied here?

Comment: Consider more generally $I_n=\int_0^1 x^nf(x) \, dx$ where $f$ is integrable. You should see that $|I_n|<M\int_{0}^1x^n\,dx$ where $M$ is a bound for $|f|$ and you are done!! You can observe that no deep theorems are needed here.

Comment: Also observe the tactics of question setter to put thing like $a, e$ in options. That's just to give a feel of a complicated question.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint: }$Let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{x^n(ax^2+ax+1)}{e^x}$, with $x\in[0,1]$.
If $x$ is fixed in $[0,1]$, then we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&&\text{if }x\in[0,1)\\\dfrac{2a+1}e&&\text{if }x=1  \end{cases}$$
so we have pointwise convergence of $f_n$ in $[0,1]$ to $f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$. Does $f_n$ uniformy converge in $[0,1]?$
Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\underset{x\in I}\sup|f_n-f|=0$?
If the answer is positive, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: I understand it .Thank you!